# Error when installing packages "sh: rbbt_Rutil.rb: command not found"

Tags: r

I have recently run into an issue in R studio when trying to install various packages from different sources. I get an error stating "rbbt_Rutil.rb: command not found." I appreciate any insight.

```
R.version

platform       x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin15.6.0                
system         x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.0                         
year           2019                        
month          04                          
day            26                          
svn rev        76424                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
nickname       Planting of a Tree
```

For example, at least two examples of installation attempts that have given me this error:

Example 1:

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("gageData")
```

Example 2:

```
require(devtools)
install_github('omarwagih/rmotifx')
```

Output from example 1:

```
Bioconductor version 3.9 (BiocManager 1.30.4), R 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Installing package(s) 'gageData'
installing the source package ‘gageData’

sh: rbbt_Rutil.rb: command not found
Error in system("rbbt_Rutil.rb", intern = T) : error in running command
Calls: source -> system
Execution halted
```

Output from example 2:

```
sh: rbbt_Rutil.rb: command not found
Error in system("rbbt_Rutil.rb", intern = T) : error in running command
Calls: source -> system
Execution halted
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Huh, that looks like a Ruby extension, but I was never aware that Bioconductor is dependent on Ruby---my system does have Ruby and had no problem. Want to try installing it just in case?

Comment: A bit of Googling [suggests that](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rbbt-util/5.25.18) `rbbt-util` is a Ruby gem supplied by the [CNIO Bioinformatics Unit](https://bioinformatics.cnio.es/) as part of a software tool named [biotools/factoid](http://ubio.bioinfo.cnio.es/biotools/factoid/git/). It would seem that these particular packages require it to be installed.

Comment: Either that or you have some old script on your system which is running as part of the installation process and looking for code that no longer exists. Maybe you installed some tool long ago and need to clean up?

Comment: Thanks for the responses! Yeah at one point I was working on another project and tried to use some programs that required ruby and the rbbt-util gem. I think the suggestion to clean up is a good one. Before I start breaking things with the rm command in terminal... Any suggestions on how to "clean up." @neilfws ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing that some script is being triggered by the install packages process. So I'd look in places like `.Rprofile`, `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` and so on for anything that looks like it's trying to run the Ruby code. Then comment it out.

Comment: This was resolved. Thank you @neifws. I had some code in my .Rprofile ' ("rbbt_Rutil.rb", intern = T) ' . I edited my .Rprofile, deleting these lines using 
file.edit(file.path("~", ".Rprofile")). Now the packages install normally. Best regards.